# Java validation approach for a set of values

Tags: java, spring, validation

I am trying to validate a set of values 'RecordStatus' and 'Condition'. Have come up with the below method.

1. Define a class RecordStatusCodition with strings recordStatus and condition.
2. Define a class RecordStatusCoditionValidator implemented as below

> ArrayList validList = 
>                new ArrayList() {{
>
> ```
>                   add(new RecordStatusCodition ("CREATED","A"));
>                   add(new RecordStatusCodition ("INSERTED","B"));
>                   add(new RecordStatusCodition ("INSERTED","A"));
>                   }};
> ```

```
public boolean isProcessed(RecordStatusCodition recordStatusCodition ) {
                    return checkList.contains(recordStatusCodition);
    }
}
```

This class is being called from my code elsewhere to check for the conditions

```
  if(!RecordStatusCoditionValidator.isProcessed(new RecordStatusCodition("","")))
               // do processing
        }
```

Similar to the above, there are various other conditions with different lists, which might have to be changed frequently

Although this works fine, I need to know if there is a better approach for this since this is something which most part of my code will be depending on?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a `Map` (`HashMap` implementation) instead of an `ArrayList`. This way you can keep the object's identificator (in this case `A` or `B`) and store its state as the value. Then, your `isProcessed` method can be reduced to

```
map.containsKey(key); //Where key is either "A", "B", etc.
```

This map shouldn't be a raw field in a class. I suggest you wrap it in your own object, one you can reference in your application instead of the raw map. That'll give you control over the different operations and allow you to do some pre or post processing in those operations.

Your `RecordStatusCondition` class can be, also, refactored into an enumeration if you like, defining the range of conditions a given object can have:

```
RecordStatusCondition.CREATED;
RecordStatusCondition.INSERTED;
```

Then, you can add an object like this:

```
recordStatusContainer.put(record.getId(), RecordStatusCondition.CREATED);
```

You can obtain a status fairly easy too with the `get()` method but remember that if you use tour own object as a key, you'll have to redefine `hascode()` and `equals()` for it to work.

As a side suggestion, if possible you can have your `RecordStatus` (or whatever object represents your main logic unit here) to know its current condition bu adding a `RecordStatusCondition` field to it.

Comment: But if we use maps, what if we have a combination 'INSERTED and A' in addition to the other combinations in validList? That would be a duplicate key,'A' yea?

Comment: @user1583803 Would they refer to exactly the very same instance of `A`? That's why I used getId() in the example assuming that every state was related to a particular instance of whatever object type it would be. Otherwise, why would `A` have multiple states? In any case, if you need multiple states use a `HashMap` with a `List<RecordStatusCondition>` or `Set<RecordStatusCondition>` value instead.